# How to get the textValue of an HTML Button

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick

Struggling as usual with the concept of 'this'

I have many buttons on a page and I wish to get the text value of a button clicked, so that I can use that value when calling a PHP script.

I am trying to use minimal bandwidth and so I thought I could possibly use the text value of my button as a variable.  So this way, I avoided giving my Button a unique ID and also avoided duplicating the value with a VAL attribute.

I have never fully understood the concept of 'this'.  I thought the values of the clicked Button, would be passed to the onClick function - obviously not or I don't know the correct syntax.

Is it possible / feasible ?

```
        <style>
            button { padding: 10px; margin-right: 20px; font-size: 1.2em; background-color: green; color: white; }
            button:hover { background-color: orange; }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <p>Click button and call php script with Button textValue as a POST variable</p>

    <button onclick="btnClick();">Quercus petraea</button>
    <button onclick="btnClick();">Betula pendula</button>
    <button onclick="btnClick();">Fagus sylvatica</button>
    <button onclick="btnClick();">Acer campestre</button>
    <button onclick="btnClick();">Acer cappodocium</button>
    <button onclick="btnClick();">Pinus thunbergii</button>

    <script>
    function btnClick() {
        var btnText = this.textContent || this.innerText;
        alert("calling AJAX PHP with POST value of the button pressed textContent = " + btnText);
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: `onclick="btnClick.call(this);"` read [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem with you implementation it setting the context of `this`. As per your current implementation `this` refers to *window* not the element which invoke the event.

You need to set the context correct, this can be achieve it using multiple ways.

Using [`.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

```js
function btnClick() {
  var btnText = this.textContent || this.innerText;
  console.clear();
  console.log("calling AJAX PHP with POST value of the button pressed textContent = " + btnText);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="btnClick.call(this);">Quercus petraea</button>
<button type="button" onclick="btnClick.call(this);">Betula pendula</button>
```

Using [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```js
function btnClick() {
  var btnText = this.textContent || this.innerText;
  console.clear();
  console.log("calling AJAX PHP with POST value of the button pressed textContent = " + btnText);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="btnClick.bind(this)();">Quercus petraea</button>
<button type="button" onclick="btnClick.bind(this)();">Betula pendula</button>
```

Passing `this` to `btnClick` function and using the argument

```js
function btnClick(elem) {
  var btnText = elem.textContent || elem.innerText;
  console.clear();
  console.log("calling AJAX PHP with POST value of the button pressed textContent = " + btnText);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="btnClick(this);">Quercus petraea</button>
<button type="button" onclick="btnClick(this);">Betula pendula</button>
```

---

However I would recommend you to get rid of inline click handler and use unobtrusive event handler

```js
function btnClick() {
  var btnText = this.textContent || this.innerText;
  console.clear();
  console.log("calling AJAX PHP with POST value of the button pressed textContent = " + btnText);
}

document.querySelectorAll(".button").forEach(function(element) {
  element.addEventListener('click', btnClick);
})
```

```html
<button type="button" class="button">Quercus petraea</button>
<button type="button" class="button">Betula pendula</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, `this` refers to the scoped object / function.

So - if you want to use the button's context, you need to pass `this` inside the `btnClick` function parameters:

```
<button onclick="btnClick(this);">Quercus petraea</button>
                           ^
```

Javascript:

```
function btnClick(btn) {
    var btnText = btn.textContent || btn.innerText;
    alert("calling AJAX PHP with POST value of the button pressed textContent = " + btnText);
}
```

Comment: This is very enlightening. I may understand 'this' a bit better now. Many thanks.

Comment: Happy to help !

Answer (score 1):

You could get the element where click is fired on, by reading `window.event.target`, see following:

```js
function btnClick() {
    var btnText = window.event.target.textContent || window.event.target.innerText;
    console.log("calling AJAX PHP with POST value of the button pressed textContent = " + btnText);
}
```

```html
<p>Click button and call php script with Button textValue as a POST variable</p>
<button onclick="btnClick();">Quercus petraea</button>
<button onclick="btnClick();">Betula pendula</button>
<button onclick="btnClick();">Fagus sylvatica</button>
<button onclick="btnClick();">Acer campestre</button>
<button onclick="btnClick();">Acer cappodocium</button>
<button onclick="btnClick();">Pinus thunbergii</button>
```

I hope it helps you, bye.

Comment: Thanks - another option

Answer (score 1):

I mate your need to pass the this varible in the onclick and then handel it

```
<html>
<body>
<p>Click button and call php script with Button textValue as a POST    variable</p>

<button onclick="btnClick(this);">Javascript 1 </button>
<button onclick="btnClick(this);"> Javascript 2 </button>
<script>
<!-- javascript function -- >

function btnClick(e) {
    var btnText = e.innerHTML;
    alert(btnText);
}
```